# How to containerize a simple Java app with H2 database

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I wrote a simple Java Web application based on Spring with H2 database. Now I want to containerise it.

I was thinking about using docker. Is that a good choice. Would there be some other tool ?

Honestly I do not know advantages of docker. I mean Java is platform independent anyway. So what makes it appealling of using Docker ?

What I also understand if you have many many containers you need a tool like Kubernetes to manage all these containers.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading [Docker Get Started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/), this will answer all your questions.

If you need a quick example of a dockerized Spring application you can check [this one](https://github.com/leszko/calculator) or read [Spring Boot with Docker guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).

Comment: aha ok. The tutorial does not say if I have to install docker on my Windows 10 machine. But I think so. Because I get the error command docker cannot be found

Comment: Yes, just install Docker for Desktop: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/